# Finding the expected value of a continuous random variable with a polynomial function. Update finding the integral.

Tags: probability

An insurance company's monthly claims are modeled by a continuous, positive random variable $X$ whose probability density function is proportional to $(x+1)^{-4}$ where $0 \lt x \lt \infty$

I need help understanding the reasoning behind the answer:

the PDF is given by:

$1 =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{k}{(1+x)^{-4}}$

Here is my first issue in the first step, where does K come from? We are given the pdf to be $\frac{1}{(x+1)^{4}}$ So to me it would stand that the function we are given is the PDF because it says thats the pdf, and we are then to find the expected value from here which would be equivalent to:

$\int_0^{\infty} x(1+x)^{-4}$ by definition of expected value

My guess would be that the words "proportional to" are key as to why we have a K introduced can someone explain this?

I understand everything except when taking the integral because and solving for 1 because I arrive at $\frac{3k}{(1+x)^4}$ rather than $\frac{-1}{3(1+x)^4}$

Taking the integral of $(1+x)^4$:

$u=1+x$ $du=1dx$ and

$\frac{u^{-4+1}}{-4+1} dx$

which gives $\frac{-3k}{(1+x)^3}$

Which gives me $k=\frac{1}{3}$ when solving $1=\frac{-3k}{(1+x)^4} \Big\vert_0^{\infty}$ rather than $k=3$ as the answer which is the correct answer. Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your guess is accurate. We are not given that the pdf *is* $1 \over (x+1)^4$, but instead that it is *proportional to* that. So, the pdf is $k \over (x+1)^4$ for some unknown $k$. But, since it is a pdf, we can work out the value of $k$, using the fact that $1 = \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ for any probability density function.

From, here, the expected value should be $\int_0^\infty x f(x) \, dx$, for the correct probability density function.